# When I use unplugin-icons, how do I render icon components dynamically in Vue

Tags: vuejs3, element-plus

When I use element-plus to create an icon component, I use unplugin-icons and unplugin-auto-import to automatically import icons, for example I use `<el-icon><i-ep-monitor />< /el-icon>` to import an icon component. Now I have a requirement, I have an array which stores some strings like `['i-ep-avatar', 'i-ep-cellphone', 'i-ep-apple']`, now what can I pass The method converts the strings in this array into components and dynamically adds them to the vue template. I hope to get your help.

```
<template>
  <el-icon>
    <i-ep-monitor />
  </el-icon>
</template>
```

When I write like this, it can be imported normally

```
    <template>
      <el-icon>
       {How should I dynamically generate a component like <i-ep-monitor /> from the string content in the array?}
      </el-icon>
    </template>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<component>` for that

details: https://vuejs.org/api/built-in-special-elements.html#component

example:

```html
<template>
  <el-icon>
    <component :is="myIcon"/>
  </el-icon>
</template>
```

where `myIcon` would return a string like `i-ep-monitor`